# Every murderer and rapist in the world vanished without a trace. How many people is that?

Tags: science-based, society, earth, population, cataclysms

In a worldwide catastrophe, every single murderer and rapist just vanished from the world at the same time. Nothing left behind, either dust, clothes, or whatever they were carrying at the moment.

There were millions of witnesses. People on the subway saw their fellow commuters go voosh right in front of them.

The criteria is as follows:

- **Murder:** Willingly and consciously terminating the life of another breathing human, regardless of any secular justification (war, legal executions, etc). Abortions are out, since fetus don't breathe. Vehicle accidents are also out, unless the vehicle driver had the intent of driving to kill (e.g. Terrorist drive-thru)
- **Rape:** Forced genital intercourse with another breathing human that is either unwilling or unable to give consent regardless of gender. Again, regardless of legal standings of a particular country. Any intercourse that is not genital on genital is disregarded.

But **how many people** did vanish that day? How to **estimate this quantity**?

---

P.S.: I am going to post other questions regarding this event, but the Stack rules say "One question per post."

Comment: Going to need specific criteria for what determines whether someone is a murderer or a rapist. Not exactly a fun jaunt into philosophy, but is it by legal definition? If so, which countries laws? Is a soldier a murderer? Someone who kills in self defense? Maybe I'm just quibbling.

Comment: Based on murder rates of 400,000-500,000 people a year globally, you'd probably get at least 25,000,000 people for just murder alone. That's a very very rough ballpark estimate. As for rape, do you mean penetrative or does any sexual assault count?

Comment: Well, start off by defining murderer and rapist. Are soldiers murderers? Are vicious barbarian types murderers? Is talking to a girl on the campus considered rape? Is having sex with a drunk or drugged girl rape? Where do you draw the lines? Are the criteria objective or relative to laws/culture? Doesn't sound like a fun topic to get into, but the definitions should be clear either way.

Comment: Same thought here. In some countries (I'm thinking of parts of Africa and Asia), the husband still owns his wife and can do whatever he wants to / with her. There cannot be rape in a marriage because the wife has no legal right to decline.

Comment: What defines rape? Mentally raping someone? Raping someone by a certain country's laws? Rape when someone was drugged or drunk and "consented" under the influence, but wouldn't normally, and the raper knew it? Rape when someone consented under repeated pressure by a boss? Forced marriage?

Comment: @Onyz yeah... a one night stand between two consensual drunks now gets the guy thrown out of college when she has second thoughts a few days later.

Comment: You are right, one question per post is ideal. You've asked 2 though. "How many people" is not answerable given your information, see the other comments. "How to estimate" however is a completely different beast. Please also consider the sandbox: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: @Raditz_35 How to estimate and how many are close enough questions to be included in one post. Any good answer t0 how many people vanished will include their working out and so will answer both questions.

Comment: @Bellerophon I don't agree. Any good answer telling you how many people will vanish will also present you with a strategy on how to estimate it. But the estimate question can be answered without giving a number. Given the complexity of the issue (see comments), I wanted to emphasize that instead of spending a lot of time figuring out what exactly murder and so on is, dropping the exact number question is a real option for the OP here

Comment: This depends on your definition of rape and murder. Some things are statutory rape in one culture and legal marriage sex in another...

Comment: So I just pay some random hobbo 10.000$ to kill my boss. Will I dissapear, or only the murederer? that could have a **huge** impact, as lot of polotical people will dissapear...

Comment: @Raditz_35 Good point.

Comment: Once this comes back, I'm sure I can at least do a Fermi approximation for it.

Comment: Based on your definition, one can force the victim into apnea and not being murder or rapist. Actually, based on your definition, drowning somebody is not murder.

Comment: @L.Dutch It seems sufficient to me. 'Unable to give consent' would cover apnea, I believe. And drowning somebody is "willingly and consciously" terminating their life.

Comment: @Onyz, but they are not breathing when their head is underwater, so they are not covered by your definition.

Comment: Who is vaporizing all of these people, if they're zapping war veterans but not zapping abortionists?  It's like you gave some Berkeley radicals control of the [Tantalus Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series))

Comment: A person who forced  another to perform acts other than genital to genital sex whilst they feared death or injury, or were unable to give consent are they not rapists?

Comment: *Any intercourse that is not genital on genital is disregarded (as rape)*  That would leave an incredible range of truly violent actual rapes excluded.  Rape is an act of violence, not intercourse.  I'm frankly offended by your definition.

Answer (score 7):

Up to a [quarter of the men](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/almost-a-quarter-of-men-in-some-asian-countries-admit-rape-8806114.html), depending on the country. Over half the men in Papua New Guinea, if you believe that article.

In the cosmic justice sense, it is hard to distinguish murder from deaths in war. There are a lot of soldiers who may be disappearing. Not only with regard to the US, there are also, particularly in Africa, very serious wars of relatively recent vintage. Hard to find numbers on 'how many people in the Congo have killed someone', but since millions in that country have died violently over the last 20 years, there are probably a lot of 'murderers' out there.

Deaths in war also bring up some good questions. Who takes the hit for a submarine launched Tomahawk missile? The crewman who hits the red button? The CO of the sub? The planner who picked the target? Clinton/Bush/Obama/Trump for approving the strike? Could be everyone who has ever worked in the Pentagon and White House disappearing.

Also, depending on your take on the 'abortion is murder' argument, [a quarter](https://www.guttmacher.org/fact-sheet/induced-abortion-united-states) or more of women in the developed world might disappear also. Alternately, perhaps only the involved doctors would disappear.

Comment: The UK doesn't consider women capable of rape. Those figures might be a lot higher

Comment: @nzaman I mean, they send [women to jail for that](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3599297/Married-geography-teacher-27-sex-16-year-old-pupil-car-six-month-affair-started-propositioned-giving-lift-home.html) in the UK, so I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Sexual assault, not rape. They may be prosecuted, but they don't show up in the "rape" statistics